# Automatically delete all unused certbot certificates

Tags: nginx, certbot

I'm aware `certbot certificates` gives me a complete list of all available certificates.

I'm also aware `certbot delete` does the same, and then gives me the ability to remove one.

However, considering certbot integrates itself with nginx and apache, is there a way to ask it to **delete all certificates which are currently not being used by nginx**?

The alternative would be opening all configurations in `/etc/nginx/site-enabled`, write down all certificates being used, run `certbot certificates`, write down all unused certificates and find them one by one in the `certbot delete` list.

Comment: The [docs](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#safely-deleting-certificates) provide an example command: `bash -c 'grep -R live/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled'`. One could take its output, subtract it from the output of `certbot certificates`, and feed the output to `certbot delete`, in a carefully written script. For extra coolness, one could utilise the Certbot API.